# Python script issue

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, video, audio

I made a script for Blender that plays a short clicking sound at certain points of the render(I am rendering a video). The render also has an audio track. This is what I used for the clicking sound:

```
    device = aud.device()
    factory = aud.Factory('sound.mp3')
    handle = device.play(factory)
```

The issue I am having is that the sound plays in the Blender UI, but not on the rendered video. What do I need to add to this code in order to have it appear on the audio track?

Comment: you would need to add that file to the VSE, then render that out. Which can be scripted, but it is by no means necessary.

Comment: ... or add via a speaker object.

Comment: and then how would I command the speaker to have it play the sound on my triggers?